# Can`t connect to WebSQL on android

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-sql

Im trying to make simple app for android, using webView and HTML5/javaScript. I want to store user data in WebSQL database.
My app works good on Android Virtual Device and from browser on PC, but when I trying to run it on my mobile phone (android 2.3.5), it cant connect to database, window.openDatabase("name", "1.0", "name", 1024*1024) returns null.
In activity.java I set webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true). Maybe I need to set anything else for older androids?

Comment: Are you sure it's supported? Try putting a support check in your JS `if(openDatabase){console.log("it's supported")};`

Comment: it works fine on android on browsers that support websql, like chrome. Other than Chrome, i'm not sure what else supports that abandoned and deprecated DB system; IndexedDB is the future-resistant client-side DB. If i had to guess, your mobile emulator mistakenly assumes it's internal webkit is the same as the android browser... You can easily polyfill IndexedDB using webSQL, but i've not seen anything going to other way...